# Blender 2.8: any alternative for changing between modes other than the (uncomfortable) pie menu?

Tags: weight-painting, shortcut

I seem to have finally switched my brain to using 2.8 shortcuts. However, the switching between weight paint/object/pose mode when painting weights for armature still gives me a lot of trouble.

It used to be so simple and elegant when Ctrl+Tab was just for Weight paint. Now it enters a confusing pie menu where I have to manually click/point towards the correct section. It adds a whole new step into what should be a very quick operation. Sure, with time I guess I could get used to it, but it seems regressive to actually ADD another step to an previously single-step operation.

I know I've got the option of using 2.79 or even the 2.79 hotkey scheme, but I don't wanna get stuck in the past. Generally I'm up for re-learning interface, it's just this single change that's really bugging me.

Is there really no single-step method to select weight paint mode now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply change the keymap in User Preferences. Or - the fast way - in the top left corner, where you have the dropdown for the modes: Click once to show all the modes, then right click on Weight Paint -> Assign Shortcut.

You can do that with almost everything in Blender 2.8.
Another Option is (in the same Context Menu) "Add to Quick Favorites". Then it will appear under the Menu that you get when pressing "Q".

Hope that helps!